# C# : Remove a Picture Content Control fro .docx

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, controls

I use the following code to find a Picture Content Control using the tagname of this one and after I use the function Remove to remove it in the Word document :

```
System.IO.File.Copy(templatePath, outputPath, true);

using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputPath, true))
{
    tagName = "portrait";
    controlBlock = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == tagName).SingleOrDefault();
    if (controlBlock != null)
    {
        controlBlock.Remove();
    }

    doc.Close();
}
```

But when I open the created file in Word, the document need to be repaired by Word if not I can't open it. Word also give me this message in the detail of error :

```
<p> elements are required before every </tc>
```

When I inspect the word document with Open Xml before and after it been repaired, I don't see any difference

So what is the best way to remove a Picture Content Control in a Word document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem easily, in fact the error message provided by Word is clear. So I get the parent element of my Picture Control Content and add a new empty paragraph and after I tried to delete the Picture Control Content and it was enough to resolved my problem.

Here is the code :

```
controlBlock.Parent.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph());
controlBlock.Remove();
```